# Cannot download package in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda

I'm in my Anaconda Navigator in my root environment, and I'm trying to download selenium. When I click on selenium in order to apply the download, the loading screen which I've shown below pops up and stays there. I also get errors when I try to install selenium via pip.
Edit: I've also tried opening the command prompt within the Navigator. Also, I am on Windows.

I've tried uninstalling everything, but the issue persists. Please help!

[image: error]

Comment: What did you do to try to install it from the command prompt? Did you try `conda install -c conda-forge selenium` ?

Comment: It says Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve, and then it proceeds to take a very long time to progress.

Comment: Maybe one of these other options will work https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium